# Proof of a set of nonzero polynomials is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

In Friedberg Linear Algebra book, Exercise 1.5.18 reads:

> Let $S$ be a set of nonzero polynomials in $P(F)$ such that no two have the same degree. Prove that $S$ is linearly independent.

However, I seems found a case that S is linearly dependent.

Suppose a sequence of real number $b_0=1$, for $i > 0$, $ b_i=-1/2^i$, then $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i = 0$.

Suppose a set of polynomials $s_0(x) = b_0$, $s_1(x) = b_0x + b_1$, $s_2(x) = b_0x^2 + b_1x + b_2$ and so on, consists the set $S$.

If the set $S$ is linearly dependent, some nonzero $a_i \in F$ satisfies $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_is_i=0$.

For all $0\leq i$, we choose $a_i = 1$. Then $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_is_i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}s_i= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_ix + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_ix^2 + ...=0 + 0x + 0x^2+ ... = 0$$
Therefore, the set $S$ is linearly dependent.
I am curious whether I made a mistake on this proof.

Comment: By definition, for an infinite set to be linearly dependent, there needs to exist some ***finite*** subset which is linearly dependent.

Comment: Wow, I missed that point. Thank you!

Comment: Linear combinations are finite sums by definition. Infinite sums don't make sense in arbitrary vector spaces. To define infinite sums, you need a topology on your vector space.

Comment: Notice that there's a simpler sequence whose coefficient-by-coefficient infinite sum would equal $0$, namely $\{1,x-1,x^2-x,x^3-x^2,x^4-x^3,\dots\}$. But as others have said, without defining what convergence of infinite sums means in the vector space in question, infinite sums are not meaningful.